# what happened if the HTTP request cache control header is different than the response cache control header

Tags: http, web, caching, http-headers, frontend

[image]

See the screenshot above. The response header has a cache-control set to `max-age`, which means the maximum amount of time a resource is considered fresh. I believe if we make a request within the time frame, the browser will serve the local copies **without bothering asking the server.** and the request header has a cache-control set to `no-cache`, that means, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control),

> response may be stored by any cache, even if the request is normally
> non-cacheable. However, the stored response **MUST** always go through
> validation with the origin server first before using it,

So here we have a contradiction:

1. the cache-control directive in the request is `no-cache`, so the user agent has to consult the server first before using the cache to fulfill the request.
2. The cache-control in response has a `max-age` being 86400, suggesting that within that time frame user agents can just use the cache to fulfill the request.

If the time specified in response's `max-age` hasn't expired, does the browser bypass the cache and send a request to the server because of its `no-cache` or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***If the time specified in response's max-age hasn't expired, does the browser bypass the cache and send a request to the server because of its no-cache or not?***

Yes, a request will be sent to the origin server. From [the specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.4):

> The `no-cache` request directive indicates that a cache MUST NOT use
> a stored response to satisfy the request without successful
> validation on the origin server.

There's no contradiction. The `max-age` in the response indicates how long it can be considered to be fresh. It doesn't obligate anyone to use it. Indeed, caching is an entirely optional part of HTTP, so sending a full request to the origin every time would also be fully compliant with the specification.

Now imagine that the response uses `no-cache` and the request uses `max-age=86400`. Again, a request would be sent to the origin server, because "the `no-cache` response directive indicates that the response MUST NOT be used to satisfy a subsequent request without successful validation on the origin server."

So the real asymmetry here is not between requests and responses, but between *caching* (optional) and *not caching* (obligatory when specified).

Comment: I still don't understand. If the front end code, i.e. the client side javascript add a cache control header that has a `max-age` in it, does that mean the response is automatically cached? Or it depends on the server side's  cache control header?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I know in my screenshot it was set by server side, but I wonder if client side can set that too. What if the client side set the max-age and the server doesn't?

Comment: @Joji max-age is a response directive, not a request directive. The client can't ask the server to set the cache age, the server tells the client how long it is safe to cache and the user-agent can decide if it wants to use the cache or not

Comment: @BernardoFerreiraBastosBraga: Actually, as you can see [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.1), `max-age` is a valid request directive: "The `max-age` request directive indicates that the client is unwilling to accept a response whose age is greater than the specified number of seconds."

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I stand corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **If the time specified in response's max-age hasn't expired, does the browser bypass the cache and send a request to the server because of
> its no-cache or not?**

Yes, it will be bypassed and sent a request to the server.

If the client sets `max-age` and there is no `max-stale` present, there is no request until the `max-age` expires. On the other hand, If the client sets `no-cache`, it always means a request sent without any conditions.

In conclusion, the `max-age` value of the current request compare to the last value of the response, and if there is no value or equal to `no-cache` that means always must send a request because the client not spouse to cache anything about that resource